# Sum of Primes always returns 0

Tags: perl

I have a code in Perl which takes in a number and adds up all the prime numbers up to that number. I keep on getting the value 0 which means it is not updating my `$sum` variable, but I don't know what else to do.

```
sub checkPrime {
    my($numb) = @_;
    $primeCheck = "prime\n";
     if ($numb == 1) {
        $primeCheck = "notPrime\n";
     }
     
     for ($i = 2; $i < $numb; $i++) {
        $mod = $numb % $i;
        if ($mod == 0) {
            $primeCheck = "notPrime\n"
        }
     }
     return $primeCheck;
}

sub sumOfPrimes {
    my($input) = @_;
    $sum = 0;
    
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $input; $i++) {
        if (checkPrime($i) eq "prime") {
            $sum = $sum + $i;
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
print sumOfPrimes(10);
```

Comment: Consider 1) renaming `checkPrime` to `isPrime`, and 2) using `1` instead of `"prime\n"` and `0` instead of `"notPrime\n"`. Then, `if (checkPrime($i) eq "prime\n"` becomes `if (isPrime($i))`

Comment: If speed is even remotely a concern, you can avoid checking all multiples of 2 (ie, doing `$i+=2` in the loop instead of `$i++`). Same thing for multiples of 5 although it requires more changes to the code. Regarding `checkPrime`, no need to check all numbers up to `$numb`:  stopping at `sqrt $numb` is enough (you might want to avoid computing `sqrt $numb` during each iteration though). Also, `return` as soon as you've found out that the number isn't a prime. Finally, since you are checking all numbers up to `$input`, using Eratosthene's sieve would be much more efficient ;-)

Comment: I explained a lot of this about a week ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939593/using-for-loop-finding-prime-number-between-1-100/66953009#66953009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing the correct string.  You include a newline character (`\n`) when you set the value, but not when you compare it.   Change:

```
    if (checkPrime($i) eq "prime")
```

to:

```
    if (checkPrime($i) eq "prime\n")
```

That is the simplest change, but you probably don't need to have `\n` in there at all.

Answer (score -1):

To sum [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) you need to identify if the number is a prime number. Let's create a function which returns 1 if the number is prime and 0 otherwise.

```
sub isPrime {
    my $n = shift;

    return 0 unless $n > 1;

    for( my $i = 2; $i < $n; $i++ ) {
        return 0 if $n % $i == 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Now go through the list of numbers and sum only those which is prime

```
    $sum += $num if isPrime($num);
```

Comment: Note that you are checking too many numbers. Once you get the the square root of the number, there's no sense checking an factors beyond that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939593/using-for-loop-finding-prime-number-between-1-100/66953009#66953009